# Quartz XML plugin reschedules fired triggers after restart

Tags: java, triggers, quartz-scheduler

I am using [XML Scheduling Plugin](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/configuration/ConfigPlugins) ([`XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.5/org/quartz/plugins/xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.html)) to create several jobs and triggers on startup in JDBC job store in [quartz-scheduler](/questions/tagged/quartz-scheduler). This works fine but I have a problem with simple triggers configured to run only once.

When such a trigger fires, it is removed from the database as there is no next fire time. So far so good. Unfortunately when I restart the application the plugin can't find that trigger so it is reinserted again. Because I use `MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_IGNORE_MISFIRE_POLICY` this job is fired again and again removed from the database. Restarting the application repeats the whole process.

Obviously I want my trigger to fire only once. Is it possible to keep fired triggers in the database even if they don't have next fire time? Or maybe this can be solved in a different way? Excerpt from my `quartz_data.xml` file:

```
<processing-directives>
    <overwrite-existing-data>false</overwrite-existing-data>
    <ignore-duplicates>true</ignore-duplicates>
</processing-directives>

<schedule>

    <trigger>
        <simple>
            <!-- ... -->
            <start-time>2012-05-10T07:00:00Z</start-time>
            <repeat-count>0</repeat-count>
            <repeat-interval>0</repeat-interval>
        </simple>
    </trigger>
```

Note that there is a problem with all triggers that reached the last execution and hence were deleted from db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up extending `StdJDBCDelegate` and overriding `deleteTrigger()` to be no-op:

```
package com.example;

class DurableTriggersDriverDelegate extends StdJDBCDelegate {

    public DurableTriggersDriverDelegate(Logger logger, String tablePrefix, String schedName, String instanceId, ClassLoadHelper classLoadHelper) {
        super(logger, tablePrefix, schedName, instanceId, classLoadHelper);
    }

    public DurableTriggersDriverDelegate(Logger logger, String tablePrefix, String schedName, String instanceId, ClassLoadHelper classLoadHelper, Boolean useProperties) {
        super(logger, tablePrefix, schedName, instanceId, classLoadHelper, useProperties);
    }

    @Override
    public int deleteTrigger(Connection conn, TriggerKey triggerKey) throws SQLException {
        this.logger.debug("deleteTrigger(" + conn + ") skipped");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The new implementation can be easily plugged-in via `quartz.properties`:

```
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=com.example.DurableTriggersDriverDelegate
```

This solution has several drawbacks:

- the database keeps growing and growing, not deleting fired triggers
- deleting job is not possible since it first tries to delete all triggers (but this is not performed) and constraint violation occurs when trying to delete the job details itself

However it solved my original problem.