# Quartz run job on startup

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'm trying ot run job one a day on specific time and on server startup to make sure that data is up to date. Unfortunately I don't know how to set quartz to run on server startup using xml file. Here is my schedule:

```
<schedule>
    <job>
        <name>UpdateDashboardStats</name>
        <group>UpdateDashboardStats</group>
        <description>Updating Dashboard Statistics</description>
        <job-class>utils.UpdateDashboardStats</job-class>
    </job>

    <trigger>
        <cron>
            <name>UpdateDashboardStats</name>
            <job-name>UpdateDashboardStats</job-name>
            <job-group>UpdateDashboardStats</job-group>
            <!-- It will run at 1am every day -->
            <cron-expression>0 0 1 * * ?</cron-expression>
        </cron>
    </trigger>
    <trigger>
        <simple>
            <name>UpdateDashboardStatsStartup</name>
            <job-name>UpdateDashboardStats</job-name>
            <job-group>UpdateDashboardStats</job-group>
            <description>Run once at startup</description>
            <misfire-instruction>SmartPolicy</misfire-instruction>
            <repeat-count>0</repeat-count>
            <repeat-interval>10</repeat-interval>
        </simple>
    </trigger>
</schedule>
```

Comment: as zerologiko mentioned Quartz scheduler must be running to pick the quartz xml. How are you validating that Quartz scheduler is running.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible to start the scheduler using just the XML configuration: you also need to **build** and **start** an instance of the Scheduler. Just start the Scheduler programmatically using:

```
scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory("quartz.properties").getScheduler();
try {
    scheduler.start();
} catch (SchedulerException e) {
    logger.error("Error getting scheduler status", e);
}
```

*This is enough to fire the triggers defined in your XML (referenced in the quartz.properties).*

---

**..But if you are using a container** (like Apache Tomcat), use the Listener or a Servlet to start a Scheduler using XML only. See [this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/cookbook/ServletInitScheduler) official documentation.

Comment: Listener is working and crone jobs are working fine. But my problem is that I want to run this specific job also on server startup.

Comment: If you are sure that cron is working, then maybe the simple trigger misfires since has no delay. 
Add this to your simple trigger configuration
<start-time-seconds-in-future>60</start-time-seconds-in-future>
See http://stackoverflow.com/a/10688983/846553

Answer (score 0):

as zerologiko mentioned Quartz scheduler must be running to pick the quartz xml.

How are you validating that Quartz scheduler is running.

Can you please mention if the your job is running at the scheduled time. Making it run for the first time would be easy.

As you already have your job. You can execute it as a separate scheduling which will not be repeated. Being executed only once

Comment: Quartz is working using listener and crone job is executing for sure.